# Cannot invoke factory class because it is null?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a registration form page index.html for users for a car rental app I'm building

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Register</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#" th:action="@{/register}" th:object="${user}"
        method="post">
  <p>User Name <input type="text" name="name"></p>
  <p>Password <input type="password" name="password"></p>
  <button type="submit">Register</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And a corresponding controller class where I want to invoke a new user using the factory class then save it to MySQL DB

Controller Class:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    private CustomerFactory userFactory;
    private UserController controller;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String registerForm(Model model){

        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/car-list")
    public String carList(){
        return "index";
    }

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public String registerUser(@ModelAttribute User user){

        User u = userFactory.createUser(user.getName(), user.getPassword());
        //userService.saveUser(user);
        return "car-list";
    }
}
```

Here is the User class:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "userID", nullable = false)
    private int userID;
    private String name;
    private String password;

    public User() {
    }
    public User(String name, String password) {
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
    }
    //getters setters and toString omitted
}
```

Here is my factory class:

```
public class CustomerFactory implements com.project.CS4125.service.UserFactory {

    @Override
    public User createUser(String name, String password) {
        return new User(name, password);
    }
}
```

My problem is I need to create the new User through the factory class then save it but get this error
: Cannot invoke "com.project.CS4125.service.CustomerFactory.createUser(String, String)" because "this.userFactory" is null

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this section of your code. How many autowired fields does it show?

```java
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    private CustomerFactory userFactory;
    private UserController controller;
```

The answer is one, the `UserService`.

Annotations such as `@Autowired` apply only to the element that immediately follows them. This section of code shows one field with an `@Autowired` annotation and two fields without this annotation. These other two fields are thus left at their default value of `null`, hence the `NullPointerException` attempting to call a method of the `CustomerFactory`.

If you want values for all three of these fields to be autowired, ensure all three fields have an `@Autowired` annotation:

```java
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private CustomerFactory userFactory;

    @Autowired
    private UserController controller;
```

Comment: This leads to another error, Field userFactory in com.project.CS4125.controller.IndexController required a bean of type 'com.project.CS4125.service.CustomerFactory' that could not be found.

Comment: Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.project.CS4125.service.CustomerFactory' in your configuration.